# Export CSV with autowidth on each cells

Tags: javascript, excel, csv, export-to-csv

I am having a problem in setting the auto-width. I want to fit all the text in a single cell where all values can be viewed without further clicks. My exported CSV currently looks like this :

[image: Exported CSV]

And the following is what I want to achieve:

[image: Achieve state]

What I've tried out so far is, convert this array of data (*stringified*)

```
[
  ["Play Date","Round","Result Virtual","Result Data"],
  ["=\"2020-03-04 00:48:00\"","16","\"[LEFT, LINE3, EVEN]\"","\"[LEFT, LINE3, EVEN]\""],
  ["=\"2020-03-04 00:51:00\"","17","\"[LEFT, LINE4, ODD]\"","\"[LEFT, LINE4, ODD]\""],
  ["=\"2020-03-04 00:54:00\"","18","\"[LEFT, LINE3, EVEN]\"","\"[LEFT, LINE3, EVEN]\""],
  ["=\"2020-03-04 00:57:00\"","19","\"[RIGHT, LINE4, EVEN]\"","\"[RIGHT, LINE4, EVEN]\""]
]
```

into CSV format and then download:

```
data.forEach(rowItem => {
  rowItem.forEach(colItem => {
    csvString += `${colItem},`
  })
  csvString += '\r\n'
})

csvString = 'data:application/csv,' + encodeURIComponent(csvString)
var x = document.createElement('A')
x.setAttribute('href', csvString)
x.setAttribute('download', `${new Date()}.csv`)
document.body.appendChild(x)
x.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Comma-Separated Values (CSV)**, as the name suggests, is nothing more than text. separated with commas. According to Wikipedia, CSV is

> *a delimited text file that uses a comma to separate values. Each line of the file is a data record. Each record consists of one or more fields, separated by commas. The use of the comma as a field separator is the source of the name for this file format. A CSV file typically stores tabular data (numbers and text) in plain text, in which case each line will have the same number of fields.*

All it has is a single 2 dimensional matrix of data. What you are trying to incorporate is to incorporate some data about **display format** of those data in a specific application (excel as it seems). This I am afraid is not possible without adding data related to the formatting the presentation of actual data, in those application. **File Content + Formatting Data -> `.csv`** is going to violate the fundamental idea behind CSV (read [this for more on CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) and [this for the RFC on CSV](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180)). That's why there are application specific formats such as `.xls`.

I don't think that it is (and should ever be) possible to do what you try to do in `.csv` format. The best avenue that you can take is to choose a different file format that better suits your requirement (such as `.xls`).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this API `RangeFormat.autofitColumns()`, here is the sample code you could try

```
async function main(context: Excel.RequestContext) {
  // Auto fit the columns of range: Sheet1!A:A
  let workbook = context.workbook;
  let worksheets = workbook.worksheets;
  let selectedSheet = worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
  selectedSheet.getRange("A:A").format.autofitColumns();
```

The document can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.rangeformat?view=excel-js-preview#autofitcolumns--